# Why negative value becomes positive after dumping into yaml file?

Tags: ruby, yaml, sinatra

I have a simple sinatra app uses yaml files to handle data. One of the feature is an `User` can vote or veto for a `Question`. The vote feature works fine, but I met some weird things when implementing the veto feature.

Briefly saying:

- when a question's current `votes_count` is positive (`>= 1`), the number will decrease correctly
- but when a question's current `votes_count` is zero or negative, the number will successfully decrease in the `data` hash, but after dump `data` hash into the yaml file, negative becomes positive.

This is the yaml file for `Question`:

```
'1': !ruby/hash:Sinatra::IndifferentHash
  title: " Best way to require all files from a directory in ruby?"
  description: What's the best way to require all files from a directory in ruby ?
  user_id: '3'
  votes_count: 0

# other user information
```

This is the route handler relates to veto feature:

```rb
post "/questions/:id/veto" do
  check_vote_validity_for_question(params[:id])
  @question = Question.find_by(:id, params[:id])
  @question.votes_count = (@question.votes_count.to_i - 1)
  Question.update(params[:id], votes_count: @question.votes_count )
  # omit user related code
end
```

This is the `update` method:

```rb
  def self.update(id, attrs)
    data = load_data_of(data_name)
    # binding.pry
    obj_info = data[id]
    attrs.each do |k, v|
      v = v.to_s if v.is_a?(Array)
      obj_info[k] = v
    end
    # binding.pry
    File.open(File.join(data_path, "#{data_name.to_s}.yaml"), "w+") do |f|
      f.write(Psych.dump(data).delete("---"))
    end
  end
```

If I pause the program inside `update` method before and after update the `data` hash, it shows the value of `votes_count` was set correctly.

Before:

```
[1] pry(Question)> data
=> {"1"=>
  {"title"=>" Best way to require all files from a directory in ruby?",
   "description"=>"What's the best way to require all files from a directory in ruby ?",
   "user_id"=>"3",
   "votes_count"=>0},
```

After:

```
[1] pry(Question)> data
=> {"1"=>
  {"title"=>" Best way to require all files from a directory in ruby?",
   "description"=>"What's the best way to require all files from a directory in ruby ?",
   "user_id"=>"3",
   "votes_count"=>-1},
```

The value of the key`"votes_count"` in `data` hash is `-1` after updating, but after I dumping the `data` hash into yaml file, the value of `"votes_count"` of the user in the yaml file became `1`. And if the value in hash is `-2`, it will become `2` in the yaml file.

I tried making  a hash which has a negative value in irb, then dump it into a yaml file, things work ok. I have no idea what happened. Could anybody help me?

Comment: "it became `1`", what does **it** refer to? Does that mean the hash you indicate in the sentence fragment before that became one? Or the value for `votes_count`? Or the key `votes_count` changed into the number `1`? Or the YAML file contains `1` as value for the key `vote_count`? Nowhere in your code `"votes_count"` is  a value, it is a *key*. Please edit your question to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: @Anthon, I edited the question.  If I have a hash like `h = { "a" => -2 }`, then after I dumping `h` into a yaml file, the content in yaml file becomes  `a: 2`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks the problem in the line

```
f.write(Psych.dump(data).delete("---"))
```

You delete `-`.

For example

```
"-1".delete("---") #=> "1"
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! That's the problem. I could have used `sub` to do this.

Comment: `YAML.dump({'a' => -2}).delete_prefix("---\n")` => `"a: -2\n"`

Comment: (since ruby 2.5)